# Validate at least one of three field in dto spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a DTO that looks something like this:

```
class VehicleDto {
    private String type;
    private Car car;
    private Bike bike;
}
```

Now depending on the type, I need to validate on at least one of Car and Bike.

Both cannot be present in the same request.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can write 2 custom validators for Car and Bike that take the type into account. Or one on class level.

Comment: if both cannot be present in the same request why the VehicleDTO contains both? It would be better to replace both car and bike fields with one vehicle type (abstract class extended by car and bike)

Comment: Can you write a sample code for that? I understand what you said, but still not sure if I am correct.

Comment: @pezetem asked another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310281/design-of-multiple-child-dtos-into-a-single-request-spring-boot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having two fields in class, while only one of them can present, seems like a design smell for me.
But if you insist on such design - you can create a custom [Validator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) for your `VehicleDto` class.

```
public class VehicleValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return VehicleDto.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {

        VehicleDto dto = (VehicleDto) obj;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "type",
                                    "error.message.for.type.field");

        if (null != dto.getType()
              && null != dto.getCar()
              && null != dto.getBike()) {
            switch(dto.getType()) {
                case "car":
                    errors.rejectValue("bike", "error.message.for.bike.field");
                    break;
                case "bike":
                    errors.rejectValue("car", "error.message.for.car.field");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, see Spring documentation about validation:

- [Validation using Spring’s Validator interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator)
- [Resolving codes to error messages](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-conversion)
- [Injecting a Validator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-inject)

Comment: What should be an ideal design for such cases?

Comment: Added a new question for the design issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310281/design-of-multiple-child-dtos-into-a-single-request-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

For example, if we want to check whether my `TaskDTO` object is valid, by comparing its two attributes `dueDate` and `repeatUntil` , following are the steps to achieve it.

**dependency in pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**DTO class:**

```
@ValidTaskDTO
public class TaskDTO {

    @FutureOrPresent
    private ZonedDateTime dueDate;

    @NotBlank(message = "Title cannot be null or blank")
    private String title;

    private String description;

    @NotNull
    private RecurrenceType recurrenceType;

    @Future
    private ZonedDateTime repeatUntil;

}
```

**Custom Annotation:**

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {TaskDTOValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidTaskDTO {
    String message() default "Due date should not be greater than or equal to Repeat Until Date.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**Constraint Validator:**

```
public class TaskDTOValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidTaskDTO, TaskDTO> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidTaskDTO constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(TaskDTO taskDTO, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (taskDTO.getRecurrenceType() == RecurrenceType.NONE) {
            return true;
        }

        return taskDTO.getRepeatUntil() != null && taskDTO.getDueDate().isBefore(taskDTO.getRepeatUntil());
    }
}
```

Make sure that you have `@Valid` in front of RequestBody of a postmapping method in your RestController. Only then the validation will get invoked:

```
@PostMapping
public TaskReadDTO createTask(@Valid @RequestBody TaskDTO taskDTO) {
.....
}
```

I hope this helps. If you need a detailed explanation on steps, have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pkaYjJVlyk)

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring-boot-starter-validation, you can validate like in

```
public static class VehicleDto {
    private String type;
    private Car car;
    private Bike bike;

    @AssertTrue(message = "You must inform either car or bike, but not both")
    private boolean isValidVehicle() {
        return (car != null && bike == null) || (car == null && bike != null);
    }
}
```